# Backup remote MySQL database from local machine

Tags: c#, mysql

I am creating an wpf application which gives user an option to backup an mysql db.I want to get this done in C# coding.

I know that it can be easily done using mysqldump, but i am stuck in an scenario where there is no mysql server installed on local machine and the user wants to back up the db located on remote machine.

So here's where i need help or any suggestion how this can be achieved as i will not get the mysqldump on local machine as mysql server is not insstalled. 
I also know that back of mysql db is not possible without using mysqldum utility provided by MySql.[did an google  over here and didnt found any helpfull post].

**What I tried :**

I was trying to embed the mysql dump with an application but somehow i was not able to.

**What I want to achieve :**

I want to create an back up of mysql db even though the user havn't installed the mysql server on his local machine.

**EDIT :** 
Is there an MySqlCommand which backups the db like the ms sql server one

> [ BACKUP DATABASE inventory TO DISK]

Answer (score 0):

This is just for the data, not the table structures, triggers, etc: an exporter to XML, see [here](http://www.platoscave.net/blog/2005/may/6/xml-data-export-from-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of the tables:

SHOW TABLES;

Get an SQL statement that will create the table:

SHOW CREATE TABLE `table_name`

Use SELECT * FROM `table_name` to get the rows and format them like

INSERT INTO (`some_field`, `another_field`, ...) VALUES ('one','two',...)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SQLyog's](http://www.webyog.com) Scheduled backup/Backup as SQL dump to backup remote MySQL database from local machine. If you have installed SQLyog on local machine you can connect to the remote server and backup using SQLyog.

Comment: tx for the reply but what i want is to just back up the db using the MySqlCommand

Comment: mysqldump –-host=the.remotedatabase.com -u yourusername -p yourdatabasename > foo.sql Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Read what i want to achieve in my question , i cant use mysqldump in the scenario where the Mysqlserver is not installed.